# PHP frameworks that aren't tightly coupled to the database and work with stored procedures?

Tags: php, mysql, database, yii

This has been coming up at work recently, and Google's been...eh, minimally useful.

We're using Yii, but company policy is that all database access has to be done through MySQL stored procedures, which "breaks" quite a bit of Yii and renders some of its attempts at making life easier, well, irrelevant.  (To be clear, the decision to require only SPs was made after Yii had been implemented.)

Are there any PHP frameworks out there that would work better under this limitation?  We're using YiiBooster, so any other framework has to be Bootstrap-compatible or the UI/UX department will start screaming.

TLDR version:

**My initial impression, from Googling and searching here, is that any other PHP framework will have the exact same limitations.**  Is this correct?

Comment: You can communicate directly to MySQL via PDO, I am 99% sure that there's no framework out there that avoids PDO or MySQLi. If you want an ORM to work while having stored procedures as the only interface towards MySQL then I'm afraid you're going to have a bad time. On the other hand, "company policy" smells like bureaucrats messing with development and that's never a good case, which ultimately leads to only one things.

Comment: Sounds to me like you should post a question about using stored procedures in this manner for development and show the result to your employers. I suspect that the feedback you get will be overwhelmingly negative.

Comment: @ShaunUK I'm a PHP developer; I have no say over what the DB team does or how.

Comment: Well you might have to communicate to them that the restriction they are placing on DB access will severely limit you as a PHP developer. Particularly as their deciscion is incompatible with your current (or perhaps even any) PHP framework.

Comment: Essentially they are asking you to move your business logic out of your layer (the PHP application) to their layer (the database) where you have less access and control over it. Creating more work for you in order to produce less risk and unknowns for them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct. Any other framework will also have this limitation.

This is because a Framework itself is an abstraction from the underlying language. The framework abstracts the php code and the orm abstracts the storage in e.g. MySQL.

What you want is another abstraction layer between the ORM and the database 'manager'. 
I'm afraid but you'll need to write your own orm or extend and orm in order to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could turn to a "microframework" that really just manages contollers, leaving you free to codes your model in an SP-compliant manner and your views in a bootstrap-compliant manner.

Answer (score 0):

Yii is extensible by its nature and does not require a DB connection to run at all.

I suggest writing your own DataProvider class, have a look at CArrayDataProvider http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CArrayDataProvider as a jumping off point.

Comment: But this question was asked a year ago and probably past its usefulness